# how to set image size in the background of canvas using Fabric.js in Angular 4+

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-canvas, fabricjs, angular8

I am using Angular 8 and fabric.js in it. I have successfully implemented a background image but can not set the image properties in angular typescript. I have tried many solutions some but most fail in angular I don't know why? 
some of them tell the way like to set background image properties but in angular, it says no such property. 
    here is my code ...

```
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("myCanvas", {

    selection: false,

    });


   canvas.setBackgroundImage(imageUrl, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {

  // in here there are some image options properties that arent working in angular


  });
  canvas.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have illustrate code in angular with stack-blitz. you can try to set background in fabric js using angular like this : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kasvob

Comment: thanks for your time i'll check and respond you soon.